# Frechet distribution approaches Pareto in right tail

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I read somewhere that Frechet distribution $G(X\leq x)=\exp(-T x^{-\theta})$ and this approaches the Pareto distribution "in the right right", i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} G(X\leq x)=1-Tx^{-\theta}.$

I just could not understand this, isn't $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} G(X\leq x)=1$ since $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^{-\theta}=0$?

I think if we take power series that $G(X\leq x)=1-T x^{-\theta}+1/2 T^2 x^{-2\theta}+\cdots$, we may kind of getting the result but when we don't take $T x^{-\theta}$ to 0 too?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the limit is not particularly meaningful as stated as all cumulative distribution functions tend to $1$ as $x$ increases without limit.

But if you let $G(x)=\exp(-Tx^{-\theta})$ and $F(x)=1-Tx^{-\theta}$  then it is meaningful to look at both the densities and survival functions and say both $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{G'(x)}{F'(x)} = 1 \text{ and } \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{1-G(x)}{1-F(x)} = 1 $$ using the power series you identified, so in this sense the two distributions approach each other in the right tail.